# how to search for partial words from a database

Tags: php, sql, database, search

I was creating a searchbox, which should work only by writing partially the value, but i don't know how? 
Here is the code:

```
  $sql = "SELECT id, name, someElse FROM My.basic_info WHERE id = '.$searched.' LIKE '%" .$searched."%' ";


    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Query to POST data from try failed: ".mysql_error());


    if ($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {




           echo $rows['id'];
           echo "<br>";

           echo $rows['name'];
           echo "<br>";

           echo $rows['someElse'];
           echo "<br>";


      } else {
        echo "What you've searched for cannot be found or isn't the correct checkbox";
        echo "<br>";
      }
```

why doesn't it work? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: check for `mysqli_error` and you'll see why!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To begin with, try removing the variable inside the string of the sql:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, name, someElse FROM My.basic_info WHERE id LIKE '%" .$searched."%' ";
```